# Limit amount of Div by Class

Tags: javascript, jquery

This should be simple, but not sure why it's not working.

Fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/8ktVh/2/

HTML

```
<div class="ocEvent">1</div>
<div class="ocEvent">2</div>
<div class="ocEvent">3</div>
<div class="ocEvent">4</div>
<div class="ocEvent">5</div>
<div class="ocEvent">6</div>
<div class="ocEvent">7</div>
<div class="ocEvent">8</div>
<div class="ocEvent">9</div>
<div class="ocEvent">10</div>
```

JQUERY

```
$('.ocEvent:gt(2)').hide();
```

Tried also div.ocEvent and also adding an id but not working.  I am wanting to limit and hide the rest of the divs, say 2.

Should be super simple, but I guess im missing something.

Comment: You aren't including the jQuery library. http://jsfiddle.net/8ktVh/3/

Comment: Are you sure you're including jquery on the page? Works fine for me.

Comment: [Here's one that works](http://jsfiddle.net/8ktVh/5/). You need to learn how to do basic debugging. Pressing `F12` in Chrome, for example, opens the dev tools which has a console

Comment: Oh weird, not working in my code either.. but I guess I have an error somewhere, I will have to check my code.  Thanks!

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because the user forgot to include jQuery.

Comment: Work just fine in your fiddle but your index is off by one if you want to show only 2 div

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code work just fine into your fiddle except maybe that your index is wrong.

If you want to show only `2 div` this should be your code:

```
$('.ocEvent:gt(1)').hide();
```

This is because `:gt` uses a zero based index.